# Error when invoke requestWhenInUseAuthorization for location permissions

Tags: swift, xcode, location, swift4, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to retrieve the user's location in the app using a location manager; as explained in Apple's documentation I created the following method:

```
func startReceivingLocationChanges() {
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if authorizationStatus != .authorizedWhenInUse && authorizationStatus != .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        startReceivingLocationChanges()
        return
    }

    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        displayError(withTitle: "Location Not Available", withDescription: "Enable Location Services at Settings > Privacy > Location Services", sender: self)
        return
    }

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100.0  // In meters.
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    locationManager.activityType = .other
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

But When I launch the app, this crash showing the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f0a7f60)" near the line:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

I specify that I added the relative "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" keys inside the info.plist.

Does anyone know what causes the issue? Thanks.

Comment: is locationManager initialized?

Comment: @Andrea Yeah, I initialized it as a class variable with “let locationManagaer = CLLocationManager()”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code like recursion in case user don’t give the permission for when in use so look at my code. Assuming you had added "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" and "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" keys inside the info.plist. Below code works perfect without any issue and apple recommended.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

typealias LocateMeCallback = (_ location: CLLocation?) -> Void

class LocationTracker: NSObject {

    static let shared = LocationTracker()

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
       let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
       locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
       locationManager.distanceFilter = 10

       return locationManager
    }()

    var locateMeCallback: LocateMeCallback?
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var isCurrentLocationAvailable: Bool {
        return currentLocation != nil
    }

    func enableLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request when-in-use authorization initially
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted, .denied:
            // Disable location features
            print("Fail permission to get current location of user")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // Enable basic location features
            enableMyWhenInUseFeatures()
       case .authorizedAlways:
            // Enable any of your app's location features
            enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
       }
    }

    func enableMyWhenInUseFeatures() {
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func enableMyAlwaysFeatures() {
       locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
       locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locateMe(callback: @escaping LocateMeCallback) {
        self.locateMeCallback = callback
        enableLocationServices()
    }

    private override init() {}

}


// MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
extension LocationTracker: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        print("locations = \(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        locateMeCallback?(location)
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        enableLocationServices()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
LocationTracker.shared.locateMe {  location in
            guard let location = location else {
                print("Cann't retrieve current location of user")
                return
            }
           // do what ever you want to do with location            
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain me what the line "typealias LocateMeCallback = (_ location: CLLocation?) -> Void" does? I know that the keyword typealias is used to add another name to a type but I don't understand of what type we're talking about.

Comment: One more question...why did you put the rounded brackets after the curly ones of the "location manager" declaration?

Comment: @LorenzoSantini, 1. typealias  define a variable LocateMeCallback ,make more readable than typing  (_ location: CLLocation?) -> Void again and again. 
2. .why did you put the rounded brackets after the curly ones of the "location manager" declaration
A: () call the closure right when you first access LocationManager similar to lazy loading, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables. Although i used locationManager is not lazy

Comment: Ok, thanks...And why did you subclass NSObject instead of just create a new class?

Comment: Welcome, if don't do this you will encounter the error "Class LocationTracker don't conform to NSObjectProtocol" for became delegate of CLLocationMagerDelegate. Which Comes from NSObject Silently. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was related somehow to the recursive call to the function

```
startReceivingLocationChanges
```

inside the function itself. I solved it asking for location permissions inside ViewDidLoad method and removing the recursive call.